# How to read an external file in Amazon Elastic MapReduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-io, amazon-emr

Hi I'm new to using Amazon EMR and Hadoop. I was wondering how to read an external file (stored in S3) from an EMR job. For example, I have a file containing a long list of blacklisted strings. When my EMR job is processing my input, how do I get the job to read in this list of blacklisted strings beforehand in order to use it during processing?

I tried using a regular Java Scanner class and hardcoding the S3 path to the file but that didn't seem to work, although I could just be doing it wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this (sorry code is scala not java, but it's the same)

- Pass the path in as a argument to your main method
- Set that as a property in your configuration

```
val conf = new Configuration()    
conf.set("blacklist.file", args(0))
```

- In the mapper's setup method, read the file:

```
var blacklist: List[String] = List()
    override def setup(context: Context) {
          val path = new Path(context.getConfiguration.get("blacklist.file"))
          val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(path.toUri, context.getConfiguration)
          blacklist = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(fileSystem.open(path)).getLines.toList
        }
```

Comment: not sure why, but the formatting isn't working, here's the second part as a github gist:https://gist.github.com/4289288

Comment: I have edited the post for you. Use an HTML comment `<!-- -->` after the bulleted line in order to have the correct code formatted.

Comment: I ended up doing basically this which worked, although I believe Amar's solution is correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you may add this file to the distributed cache as follows :

```
...
String s3FilePath = args[0];
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI(s3FilePath), conf);
...
```

Later, in configure() of your mapper/reducer, you can do the following:

```
...
Path s3FilePath;
@Override
public void configure(JobConf job) {
s3FilePath = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(job)[0];
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(s3FilePath.toString());
// Read the file and build a HashMap/List or something which can be accessed from map/reduce methods as desired.
...
}
```